# Laravel 5.1 How to Log - PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of X bytes exhausted Illuminate/Database/Connection.php

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am having this random out of memory issue in my production for specific api's calls. Laravel log has nothing logged. I am not able to figure out for what parameters it is going out of memory.

Laravel log I get following message

`[2019-03-29 00:00:24] production.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 84375216 bytes) in /var/www/biz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:321 
Stack trace: #0 {main}`

Stack trace only has this one line `#0 {main}`

Is there a way to setup `register_shutdown_function` and put it in Laravel log somewhere, where in I can put the stack trace. Or any other way to log the error and stack trace for the same to get the request parameter when the exception happens?

Comment: Does it say on what lines it happens? Are you dealing with graphics or large objects when this error happens?

Comment: It does say what line it is, there are thousands of calls and it happens randomly, thus I needed for what input parameters it went out of memory. Following is the error that I get, it is when it is trying to connect to DB.
`[2019-03-29 00:00:24] production.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 84375216 bytes) in /var/www/biz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:321
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
`
Stack trace only has this one line `#0 {main}`

Comment: Maybe it's the same issue [as this](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/23415)? If so - Try the suggested solution and subscribe to get notifications on any updates for this bug

Comment: Maybe, thread says 5.5, My application is on 5.1. Let me see if the 5.5 fix helps in 5.1.

Comment: I was able to figure out the issue. It was trying to get huge amount of data from DB and thus it went out of memory. I will put an answer explaining how I did the debugging to get the request parameters to figure out the random behavior.

Comment: Some requests are pulling huge amount of data at once, that's why. Consider using Cache in memory like Redis or Memcached for some minutes or hours to free your DB connection. And to resolve memory issue try to allow more Memory only for those special requests at the beginning of @action method code like : `ini_set('memory_limit','256M');` for more memory, and `ini_set('max_execution_time', 60);` because the greater the Data size, the more time the process needs to handle it. But Redis cache will help you a lot not to start to loose more requests soon the way I see it.

Comment: @KeitelDOG Sounds Interesting, but unfortunately I didn't understand how to dynamically decide the memory limit and execution time, It would kind of you if you can explain this a bit more, or point me to something to read about this kind of implementation in laravel or php.